# Play Framework has slow reload times when refreshing chrome

Tags: java, html, playframework

I started building a Play app using a [sample template](https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play&project=play-samples-play-java-jpa-example). But even when I make a minor html change it takes 30 seconds to refresh chrome and see my changes. This is making the framework unusable. Has anyone seen this much of a delay before and know what the problem could be? [This is a link to a video recording of the problem.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IukPddV1yJaymOCOU2rLN35BMMfNto0p)

I'm using Java for this sample, not Scala. **Below is the output from the sbt shell:**

```
--- (RELOAD) ---



[info] p.a.d.HikariCPConnectionPool - Shutting down connection pool.
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] initialized at jdbc:h2:mem:play;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
[info] p.a.d.HikariCPConnectionPool - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] p.a.d.HikariCPConnectionPool - datasource [default] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

    play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
    play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter

[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev) (no global state)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\talai\Desktop\GameExchange\play-samples-play-java-jpa-example\target\scala-2.13\classes ...
[info] Done compiling.

--- (RELOAD) ---



[info] p.a.d.HikariCPConnectionPool - Shutting down connection pool.
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] initialized at jdbc:h2:mem:play;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
[info] p.a.d.HikariCPConnectionPool - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] p.a.d.HikariCPConnectionPool - datasource [default] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

    play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter



    play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
    play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter

[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev) (no global state)
```

Comment: It does seem long. What's the output in the console? Is your computer particularly old/slow?

Comment: do you have any info in the console?

Comment: @VM4 and jacks, thanks for offering to help. I've updated my question with the console output from the sbt shell

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this one. It looks like it could be taking long because the DB is being reinitialised on every update. This is not supposed to be happening. It's possible that Hibernate needs some configuration. If you don't care about using hibernate I'd try a more simple example using Ebean. Like this one: https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-java-ebean-example